# I get plenty warnings of missing files in xcworkspace

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

I recently upgraded my code to Swift 3 and I had many problems with cocoapods but that was resolved positively. I removed or upgraded some pods and all of the sudden I get 117 warnings - files are missing in /Pods/... directory.

Is there some way for "reset" workspace or does anyone have experience with this situation?

Comment: I think that all pods is written according to  swift 2.2 langauge So it wont work in swift 3.0, You have change all syntax according to swift 3.0  then it will work

Comment: No, I'm using swift 3 version, authors did their part and upgraded their code. The thing is I removed ads but got plenty of warnings about missing files - for ads - which I don't want.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone encounters this situation just do `git add -u` in your terminal